# Enter key javascript keypress not working

Tags: javascript, submit, message, enter, keycode

I've got a bit of Javascript which the end goal is for whenever the "enter" key is pressed, a message is appended to my unordered list. Right now, any key that is pressed is appended rather than it just being the "enter" key. For example if I typed "Y", that would be submitted on the press of any other button. Obviously, all I want is data thats been typed into the text-box, submitted through "enter".

My HTML:

```
<ul id="messagebox" >
</ul>

<div>
    <input type="text" id="typetextbox" maxlength="120" autocomplete="off" />
    <button type="submit" id="submit" onblur="submit"> </button>
</div>
```

Here is the button trigger piece of Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#typetextbox').keypress(function (e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13 );
        $('#submit').click();
    });
});
```

And here is the Javascript that works for appending the messages:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var message = $('#typetextbox').val();
        $('#messagebox').append(message + "<br/>");
        $("#typetextbox").val("");  
    });
});
```

Why isn't it singling out just the Enter button to submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keyCode` is actually a property of the event, so you have to use `e.keyCode`.
Also you were calling `if(keyCode == 13 );`: that semicolon (`;`) right after the closed parenthesis, ends the if-statement immediately, so the next line of code is always executed.

Here is the correct code:

```
$('#typetextbox').keypress(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13 ) $('#submit').click();
});
```

To append the message to the `ul` element you should create a `li` element first, then append it to the `ul` element.

Here is the correct code:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var message = $('#typetextbox').val();

    if (message.replace(/ /g, '')) // If the text is not empty (e.g. nothing or only spaces)
        $('#messagebox').append( $('<li>', {text: message}) );
    $("#typetextbox").val("");  
});
```

By the way, you don't need the `$(document).ready` function to do this. Just put your script after the textarea in the dom and it will work fine.

**HERE'S THE FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/t7q4j/1/**

Comment: I've tried that, and it still has the same results. I wonder if it conflicts with the other piece of Javascript? I wouldnt have thought it should though. With this code, still, whatever I type is submitted. Thanks for the edit though!

Comment: Thank you Marco! This worked. For a side question, do you know how to disable appending a message when nothing is entered? As for right now you can press enter and that is submitted as a blank line. Thanks again!

Comment: Edited the answer, check out now :)

Answer (score 1):

update html code as

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="typetextbox" onkeypress="return keyPress(event)"  maxlength="120" autocomplete="off" />
    <button type="submit" id="submit" onblur="submit"> </button>
</div>
```

***java script implementation:***

for every keypress the function `keyPress(event)` will be called.

the function definition can be

```
var keyPress = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        send();
    }
    return true;
}
```

the function send consists of code for updating the message box

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, it's working properly.

```
$(document).on("keypress", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        alert('You hit me')
    }
})
```